# Loading a form into an iframe

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, iframe, bookmarklet

I want to load a form into an iframe. The iframe will be loaded into a random page when the user clicks the bookmarklet.

Here is the code so far:

```
    loginForm = document.createElement("form");
    loginForm.setAttribute("method","Post");
    loginForm.setAttribute("action","http://devserver:8000/action/");
    parameters = {};
    parameters['url'] = parent.window.location;

    for(var key in parameters)
    {
        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField.setAttribute('type',"hidden");
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name',key);
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value',parameters[key]);
        loginForm.appendChild(hiddenField);
    }

    loginIFrame = document.createElement('iframe');
    loginIFrame.src = "about:blank";
    loginIFrame.appendChild(loginForm);
    loginIFrame.style.top = "0px";
    loginIFrame.style.position='fixed';
    loginIFrame.style.display = 'block';
    loginIFrame.style.zIndex = 100;
    loginIFrame.style.border = "solid #48D236 10px";
    loginIFrame.height = "25px";
    loginIFrame.width = "100%";
    loginIFrame.style.border = 0;
    loginIFrame.id = "loginFrame";
    loginIFrame.name = "loginFrame";
    usernameField = document.createElement("input");
    usernameField.type = "text";
    usernameField.size = 8;
    usernameField.name = "usernameField";
    usernameField.id = "usernameField";

    passwordField = document.createElement("input");
    passwordField.type = "password";
    passwordField.size = 8;
    passwordField.name = "passwordField";
    passwordField.id = "passwordField";


    submitButton.style.position='fixed';
    submitButton.style.top = "60px";
    submitButton.type = "button";
    submitButton.value = "Submit";
    submitButton.onclick = function(){loginUser();};*/
    b.style.position="relative";


    addToBody(loginIFrame);
    loginForm.submit();
```

What ends up happening is the entire page gets reloaded on the submit (last line of code) rather than the iframe. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try adding the form using `loginIFrame.contentWindow.document` instead of `loginIFrame.appendChild`.

You might also need to add your form after the iframe has been added to the page since the `contentWindow` property won't be available.

I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure that form isn't being added to the iframe, because you are using `appendChild`. I really don't think you can manipulate it that wa since it will be loading the URL you tell it to load (i.e. about:blank).

Edit: You might also want to add `loginForm.setAttribute("target", "loginFrame");`

Here is what I've been testing with and it works fine:

```
loginIFrame = document.createElement('iframe');
loginIFrame.src = "about:blank";
loginIFrame.style.top = "0px";
loginIFrame.style.position='fixed';
loginIFrame.style.display = 'block';
loginIFrame.style.zIndex = 100;
loginIFrame.style.border = "solid #48D236 10px";
loginIFrame.height = "100px";
loginIFrame.width = "100%";
loginIFrame.style.border = 0;
loginIFrame.id = "loginFrame";
loginIFrame.name = "loginFrame";

document.body.appendChild(loginIFrame);

var idocument = loginIFrame.contentWindow.document;

loginForm = idocument.createElement("form");
loginForm.setAttribute("target", "loginFrame");
loginForm.setAttribute("method","Post");
loginForm.setAttribute("action","http://devserver:8000/action/");
parameters = {};
parameters['url'] = parent.window.location;

for(var key in parameters)
{
    var hiddenField = idocument.createElement("input");
    hiddenField.setAttribute('type',"hidden");
    hiddenField.setAttribute('name',key);
    hiddenField.setAttribute('value',parameters[key]);
    loginForm.appendChild(hiddenField);
}

loginIFrame.appendChild(loginForm);

loginForm.submit();
```

- Christian

Comment: Hmm I changed the ending to include the loginForm = loginIFrame.contentWindow.document.createElement("form"); but it doesn't redirect on the action/submit with firefox. On chrome it does. On firefox it just stays at the .src I set the iframe to. Any ideas?

Comment: Personally I would take a different approach for the bookmarklet. If you put all your code in the bookmarklet you won't be able to change anything unless you force people to update. I would make a simple bookmarklet which appends an iframe into the page. Have the iframe point to a page that does all the rest of the work. Unless you need access to the parent window within the iframe?

Comment: I do and to get around the cross-scripting here is what I do: load iframe into page that submits a post request to my server containing the url info I need -> server returns a page that makes another request to my server using the url data I passed (I need to make this a seperate request as I need to check if the user is logged in) -> server returns a response back to the user telling them if their request was successful

Comment: Fixed my answer. Let me know if you are still having troubles.

Comment: Don't you need a `var` before the first `loginForm`?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly set the form target to the iFrame. I'm imagining, since you're creating elements within the "parent" page context, it's using the main page as a target (even though it's embeded).

*EDIT*
You could also try calling createElement from the iFrame after you've created it to keep context too.